# Why are command line instructions not affecting my Plone site?

Tags: plone

I'm using [Bika Lab System](http://www.bikalabs.com/) which uses Plone, running on Ubuntu 14.04 (on a virtual machine) and NGINX 1.4.6. Plone is setup as a cluster, not an instance.

I'm trying to terminate Plone using the command line

```
./bin/plonectl stop
```

but even though the terminal says that Plone is not running, the website still works normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you started your components in foreground mode and that they are running in other (or disconnected) console sessions?

If that's not it, you may have multiple Plone installations on the machine.

Use a process monitor like `ps` or `top` to check for running instances.

Comment: How would I check if this is the case?

Comment: @mtanti: As SteveM wrote, you can use `ps aux | grep python` to get a list of all python processes.

Comment: With pgrep and pkill you can use any part of the pathname of the script.  For example my dev Plone runs from a 'Plone' folder, so I can use `pgrep -f Plone` to get all PIDs, and `pkill -9 -f Plone` to slaughter them, without regard.