# Why are file changes not affecting my Plone site?

Tags: plone

I'm using [Bika Lab System](http://www.bikalabs.com/) which uses Plone, running on Ubuntu 14.04 (on a virtual machine) and NGINX 1.4.6. Plone is setup as a cluster, not an instance.

I'm changing .pt files in the buildout-cache folder in order to change the website. This worked. However when I try to change .py Python files in the eggs directory nothing seems to happen, not even after I remove the .pyc and .pyo files. I even replaced an image and the website wasn't affected. I suspect that I'm changing the wrong directory but when I access the image from the browser the new image is displayed, so I can't see how its the wrong directory.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this an upgraded version of your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333774/why-are-command-line-instructions-not-affecting-my-plone-site)? If you have something to add, edit the previous one.

Comment: No it's a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running Plone in debug mode, it checks the file system for changes in templates and resources like stylesheets and javascript files.

It does *not* check or reload Python files. When you change a Python file, you must restart your clients to see the changes.

If you are in a development cycle, you may wish to use [plone.reload](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.reload) in conjunction with debug mode in order to be able to reload Python and ZCML without restarting the Zope instance. For this to work, you'll need to be developing with a single ZEO client or a stand-alone Zope/Plone instance. You would never really be doing development with multiple ZEO clients active anyway, would you?

Comment: How do I ensure that there is only one ZEO client active?

Comment: The easy answer is: start only one. If you are using plonectl, you may individually start and stop components. So, a one start in debug mode:

plonectl zeoserver start;
plonectl client1 fg